# Spring boot webapp fails to start

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I am getting a bunch of errors while building a spring boot web app. If I just build the project and not run it it works fine.

I am a few days into spring and cannot understand what is wrong.

Here is the application.properties file

```
server.port = 9000
    logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mschema
    spring.datasource.username=
    spring.datasource.password =
    spring.jpa.show-sql=
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
    spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
    spring.security.user.name=
    spring.security.password.password=
```

here is the build.gradle.kts file

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.31"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.31"
    id ("war")
}

group = "in_.co.innerpeacetech"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-dev-04"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    //added by pt
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    implementation("io.micrometer","micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation( "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.3.1.RELEASE")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0")
    // implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    // implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    // implementation("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.30.4")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The Logs.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-16 11:12:45.075 ERROR 5876 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.PurusharthWebApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.PurusharthWebAppKt.main(PurusharthWebApp.kt:35) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:162) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:326) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@368239c8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:455) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Logs after adding `debug=true` in the application properties

```
2021-08-16 11:49:21.775  WARN 1048 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.PurusharthWebApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2021-08-16 11:49:21.978 DEBUG 1048 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

    None


Negative matches:
-----------------

   SpringfoxWebFluxConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - not a servlet web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   Swagger2ControllerWebFlux:
      Did not match:
         - did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   Swagger2ControllerWebMvc:
      Did not match:
         - not a servlet web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   Swagger2WebFluxConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   Swagger2WebMvcConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - not a servlet web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebFluxRequestHandlerProvider:
      Did not match:
         - did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider:
      Did not match:
         - not a servlet web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None



2021-08-16 11:49:22.041 ERROR 1048 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.PurusharthWebApp]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at in_.co.innerpeacetech.bkp.PurusharthWebAppKt.main(PurusharthWebApp.kt:35) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:162) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:326) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@368239c8]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:455) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Remove the `providedRuntime` dependency on tomcat. It is needed and not provided and is already included in `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: I removed the dependency, the same errors still appear.

Comment: Also remove the version from the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency. If the error persists either your jars downloaded are borked or you aren't showing everything you are doing. Another thing I noticed, you are building a war file why? Just build a jar file.

Comment: I downloaded the jars again and it has started working, thanks!! as for the war file the senior dev said that a war file is needed to run on tomcat. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it is if you deploy it on tomcat (you can also run it standalone). If you are building a war than put the `providedRuntime` dependency back (else it might mess up dependencies).

Comment: ok M, will do. Thanks